# Find descending and ascending patterns in a range of values

Tags: python, list

I have an array of elements  like this –

```
[30,30,30,30,31,32,31,30,29,28,27,28,29,30,31,32,32,33,34,35,35,35,34,33,32,31,30,29,28,29,30,31…]
```

In this array, there is a pattern that occurs two times , the range of values descend and ascend on two occasions. Other times they are just values.

If I wish to write a function in python, that can recognize these descending and ascending patterns  and store those values,  what can be a possible logic.

**Input:**

```
c = [30,30,30,30,31,32,31,30,29,28,27,28,29,30,31,32,32,33,34,35,35,35,34,33,32,31,30,29,28,29,30,31]
```

**Code:**

```
def patterns(c):
    b=[0]
    for i in range(1, (len(c)-1)):
        if c[i]>c[i+1]:
            
            
            num_iter=i
        
            if c[i]<c[i+1]:
                b[i]=c[i]
                num_iter=i
                i+=i
            else :
            
                i+=i
                # b[i]=np.append(b[i])
        else :
            i+=i
            
    return b[i]

x=patterns(c)
```

I get the following error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'i' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: @twothreezarsix In Python loop variables persist after the loop ends.

Comment: What's your desired output?

Comment: I don't get that error on your input. I get "IndexError: list index out of range." Could you provide the full stack trace?

Comment: My desired output is to have two output array that contain the values  [32,31,30,29,28,27,28,29,30,31,32] that is the first whole descending and ascending pattern together and [35,34,33,32,31,30,29,28,29,30,31] respectively. So two array outputs, containing two patterns.